# Can amplify import cognito user pool from a different account?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have many Amplify applications belonging to different AWS accounts, and I want to maintain a single Cognito user pool in a different account. Is there a way that these Amplify applications can import the Cognito user pool of a **different** AWS account?